# How to create WinRT C# dll api

Tags: c#, dll, windows-runtime

I am creating an app that I would like to have an achievement system for. Instead of this being saved only in the app I want the system to be more of an API so I can store user info in a database as well as use this system in my other apps. I also may make this available to other developers too as an alternative to Xbox Live on Windows 8.

I am just doing some early testing and learning as I go along. I have the code that will show notifications upon a button click or something else:

```
ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04;
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Achievement Unlocked! - ICE"));
        toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Your First Achievement"));
        toastTextElements[2].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("You gained 10IP!"));
        XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs28/f/2008/167/b/c/Pipboy_by_nully1.png"); //just a fun test photo
        ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "red graphic");
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

How would I go about putting this into a dll so that you could call it without having to use a big code block like this everytime?

I hope that makes sense. If not, please tell me and I will try to explain further! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a C# windows runtime component and encapsulate your API in a class.  Then you'd need to ship the winmd file which implements your class (and potentially the DLL associated with it if you need to C# features beyond those supported in the winrt API surface) to customers along with steps to add the appropriate registration information to their appx manifest. That should allow you to create a redistributable component that others can use.